# How to nest query child's child table data

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a many to many table called users -> tasks, I can query tasks out with this:

```
var user models.User
    DB.Find(&user, "user_addr=?", userAddr)
    //log.Infof("find user: ", user)
    DB.Model(&user).Related(&tasks, "Tasks")
```

But, in my tasks, I have a child table with is one to many, called subtasks. How do I query it out as a feild in tasks. Here is my tasks structure:

```
type Tasks struct {
    gorm.Model
    TasksID int `json:"tasks_id"`
    // TasksCreateTime is the hash value since it is unique
    //TasksHash string `json:"tasks_hash"`
    // tasks related fields
    TasksTitle string `json:"tasks_title"`
    TasksCreateTime time.Time `json:"tasks_create_time"`
    TasksComment string `json:"tasks_comment"`
    SubTasks []SubTask `json:"sub_tasks" gorm:"foreignkey:ID"`
}
```

I want query the data out and assign it to SubTasks field.

How to do it nested?

If this way works or not?

```
func FetchSyncTasksForUser(userAddr string, tasks *[]models.Tasks) {
    log.Infof("fetch sync tasks for user %s ", userAddr)
    var user models.User
    DB.Find(&user, "user_addr=?", userAddr)
    DB.Preload("Tasks").Preload("Tasks.SubTasks").Find(&user, "user_addr = ?", userAddr)
    tasks = &user.Tasks
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the definition of your `User` struct as well?

Comment: @EminLaletovic yes, its almost same as first answer says.

Comment: Does anyone knows why I still got empty tasks returned: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66532695/golang-copy-a-struct-filed-of-list-to-a-new-list-got-empty But inside func is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the gorm Preload feature? I put together this code snippet which preloads the necessary models. It will print out the formatted models to the command line.

Update: Includes a snippet to find a user by their ID https://gorm.io/docs/query.html

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name  string
    Tasks []Task
}

type Task struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserId   uint
    SubTasks []SubTask
}

type SubTask struct {
    gorm.Model
    TaskId uint
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    // Migrate the schema
    db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &Task{}, &SubTask{})

    // Create
    user := User{Name: "C"}
    db.Create(&user)

    task := Task{UserId: user.ID}
    db.Create(&task)

    subTaskOne := SubTask{TaskId: task.ID}
    subTaskTwo := SubTask{TaskId: task.ID}
    db.Create(&subTaskOne)
    db.Create(&subTaskTwo)

    // Find all users, with tasks and subtasks
    users := make([]User, 1)
    db.Preload("Tasks").Preload("Tasks.SubTasks").Find(&users)

    for _, u := range users {
        jsonOutput, err := json.MarshalIndent(u, "", "  ")
        if err != nil {
            panic("")
        }
        fmt.Println(string(jsonOutput))
    }

    // Find only one user by user_addr with tasks and subtasks

    oneUser := User{}
    db.Where("user_addr = ?", user.UserAddr).Preload("Tasks").Preload("Tasks.SubTasks").First(&oneUser)

    jsonOutput, err := json.MarshalIndent(oneUser, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        panic("")
    }
    fmt.Println(string(jsonOutput))

    // Clean up
    db.Delete(&subTaskTwo)
    db.Delete(&subTaskOne)
    db.Delete(&task)
    db.Delete(&user)
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir @Christian Your answer is so good. What if I just want all tasks belongs to user_id == 1? I mean, query specific tasks of one user. And my obstacle is get the tasks along with it's subtasks

Comment: @NicholasJela I have updated my answer with how to do this. The second parameter you pass to `Find` can be a primary key to look for. This is in the docs https://gorm.io/docs/query.html The code above returns both the user's tasks *with* the subtasks also embedded.

Comment: Hi Sir, would u help check if this work or not (logical): func FetchSyncTasksForUser(userAddr string, tasks *[]models.Tasks) {
 log.Infof("fetch sync tasks for user %s ", userAddr)
 var user models.User
 DB.Find(&user, "user_addr=?", userAddr)
 //
 DB.Preload("Tasks").Preload("Tasks.SubTasks").Find(&user, "user_addr = ?", userAddr)
 tasks = &user.Tasks
}

Comment: See updated answer - if the answer is correct. Please would you mark it as accepted?

Comment: I still got a problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66532695/golang-copy-a-struct-filed-of-list-to-a-new-list-got-empty which returns tasks is empty. Do u know why?

Comment: Hi @NicholasJela if this answer is correct, please could you mark it as accepted so it is easy for others to find the answer if they have the same question. The link to your other question is broken.